# passing parameter between functions on python

Tags: python

I try to use a parameter of another function. I prefer to not use global variable. I try the following one, but I have an error. I search in google and here but I haven't found something to help me

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        ******
        all_list = *a list*  
        ******

    def post(self):
        for i in self.all_list:
           if i[0] == something:
                   ****
```

And I have this error: `AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute 'all_list'`

Comment: You didn't store `all_list` in `.get()` on `self`.. And this is about managing instance state, not about passing parameters between functions (or methods).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
self.all_list = *a list*
```

`self` is the instance that gets passed to the function, what you are doing at the moment is just setting a local variable to the function.

Comment: @Tasos You must have called `post` before you called `get`. You probably want to set up `self.all_list = []` in the `__init__` method

Comment: Nop. I call post after get. That's for sure. Also, I don't have any __init__ method. I will create one only for this?

Comment: @Tasos Oviously you don't... or this error wouldn't arise, put some debugging statements into your code and it's probably best to create an `__init__` method to set up and empty `[]`

Comment: I use jinja framework. Get is the function to load the page and post when someone submit a form. So, first 'get' called to load the page and then 'post' when form submited.

Comment: Yes. I put self.all_list to both defs. Sorry if bother you, but I cannot really find a way

Comment: @Tasos The error must be elsewhere, possibly an indentation error eg. mixing tabs and spaces or something like that.

Comment: I tried global var too, but I have the same error. Probably jinja remove all var after calling get. I can't see any other reason.

Comment: @Tasos I can't guess any more than I already have, you would have to provide more of the code in the question next time